# What kind of index should I use in MYSQL with MYISAM table engine

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, myisam

What kind of indexing should I use for below query? Please note I'm using MySQL and MYISAM storage engine and table contains over 6M rows I need to get result faster. I'm ready to do memory tradeoff for this thanks

```
    SELECT 
            `track-item-number` AS awb,
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(`last-known-location-cd`) ORDER BY last_update SEPARATOR '> ') as PATH,
            `pickup-route-number` AS pickupRoute,
            `service-type` AS service,
            `ursa-code`  AS ursa,
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(`shipper-reference-notes`) SEPARATOR '|') as REF,
            MIN(`ship-date`) AS shipDate,
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(`delivery-date-time`) SEPARATOR '|') as deliveryDateTime,
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(`received-by-name`) SEPARATOR '|') as receivedBy,
            `shipper-account-number` AS shipperAccount,
            `bill-to-account-number` AS billtoAccount,
            `weight-uom` AS weightType,
            `shipment-weight` AS weight,
            `shipment-weight-uom` AS shipWeightType,
            `dim-source` AS dimSource,
            `package-weight-source` AS pkgWeightSource,
            `svc-commit-date` AS serviceCommitDate,
            `svc-commit-time` AS serviceCommiteTime,
            `pkg-length` AS pkgLength,
            `pkg-width` AS pkgWidth,
            `pkg-height` AS pkgHeight,
            `tracking-item-form-cd` AS trackingItemCode,
            `dim-volume` AS dimVolume,
            `doc-nondoc-flag` AS docFlag,
            `service-area` AS serviceArea,
            `tracking-item-unique-id` AS trackingUniqueId,
            `packaging-type` AS pkgType,
            `ese-generation-timestamp` AS eseTimestamp,
            `shipment-pkg-number` AS pkgNumber,
            `shipment-pkg-count` AS pkgCount,
            `package-weight` pkgWeight,
            `carrier-oid` AS carrierOid,
            `svc-commit-timestamp` AS serviceCommitTimestamp,
            `operational-scan-count` AS opScanCount,
            `dim-volume-uom` AS dimWeightType,
            `revenue-system-routing-cd` AS revSystemRouteCode,
            `revenue-dt` AS revDate,
            `unique_id`,
            `last_update`,
            `id`,
            `cosmos-dspch-nbr` AS dispatchNbr,
            `cer-id` AS cerId,
            `lpar-state` AS lparState,
            `lpar-disposition-state-cd` AS lparStateCode,
            `return-type-cd` AS returnTypeCode,
            `return-reason-group` AS returnReasonGroup,
            `recipient-account-number` AS recipAccountNumber,
            `shipper-tax-id-nbr` AS shipperTaxId
    FROM 
            `track_db`.`shipment-profile`
    WHERE
            `ship-date`>20160201 and
            `ursa-code` not like '%DACA' AND
            `ursa-code` not like '%CGPA' AND
            `ursa-code` not like '%ZYLA' 
    GROUP BY
            `track-item-number`
```

I've tried

```
    ALTER TABLE `track_db`.`shipment-profile` ADD KEY track_index(`track-item-number`, `ship-date`, `ursa-code`)
```

but no use :(

EXPLAIN

```
# id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
 '1', 'SIMPLE', 'shipment-profile', 'ALL', 'track_index', NULL, NULL, NULL, '4609925', 'Using where; Using filesort'
```

Possible return rows 25,000 to 30,000.

My key_buffer_size is 2 GB

MySQL version 5.6.29

after doing

```
  ALTER TABLE `track_db`.`shipment-profile` ADD KEY track_index(`ship-date`, `track-item-number`)
```

EXPLAIN

```
   # id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
    '1', 'SIMPLE', 'shipment-profile', 'ALL', 'track_index', NULL, NULL, NULL, '4610387', 'Using where; Using filesort'
```

Now using `right('ursa-code', 4) not in ('DACA', 'CGPA', 'ZYLA')` but not much improvement
EXPLAIN

```
 # id, select_type, table,            type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref,    rows,      Extra
 '1', 'SIMPLE',  'shipment-profile', 'ALL', 'track_index', NULL, NULL,   NULL, '4661631', 'Using where; Using filesort'
```

Table status command

```
  table_name      |Engine|Version|Row_format|table_rows|Avg_row_length|Data_length|Max_data_length|Index_length|Data_free|Auto_increment|    Create_time    |    Update_time    |     Check_time    | table_collation|Checksum|Create_options|table_comment
  shipment-profile|MyISAM|   10  |  Dynamic | 4738574  |      727     | 2719772024|281474976710655|140731392   |    0    |    4738575   |2016-03-02 17:20:02|2016-03-05 10:55:40|2016-03-02 17:25:20| utf8_general_ci|        |              |
```

Comment: Insufficient information to help you. We know nothing about your hardware, how many results you're getting back, there's no table structure posted in the question nor the output of `EXPLAIN`. Every single MySQL related question contains info I mentioned. Throwing indexes around and listening to bad advice (such as the one made @FakhruddinUjjainwala) will get you nowhere. Post the info I mentioned, you'll get relevant and accurate help. By a quick glance, you're doing full table scan. Converting to `InnoDB` and raising `buffer_pool_size` will let you use RAM for I/O instead of HDD.

Comment: Your query relies on the only full group by sql mode not being enabled. This mode is switched on by default in the newer versions of mysql.

Comment: Definitely leave `ursa-code` out of the index, since your pattern start with a wildcard character and indexes cannot be used for those criteria. Since the where criteria is applied before the group by, you should reverse the order of the fields in the key. What is the significance of the last 4 letters of the `ursa-code` field? Perhaps you could denormalise and create a field that contains those 4 letters only and then you could use index to speed up filtering on that field.

Comment: going to try   ALTER TABLE `track_db`.`shipment-profile` ADD KEY track_index(`ship-date`, `track-item-number`),   ursa_code is actually location code which may contain 4-6 characters. I need information of items originated from certain location

Comment: After your edits, it's clear you have two problems. First problem is efficient querying. You use a `LIKE` search with a wildcard, that usually always produces a full table scan. Indexing can only get you so far.  Second problem is sending a lot of records back - the software that receives those 30k rows back probably contributes to the overall experience.. You can use `SET PROFILING = 1; <issue your query>; SHOW PROFILE ;` to see how long it really takes for MySQL to perform work.

Comment: @Mjh regarding getting that large number of data I've done json_encode->gzdflat->base64encode lastly urlencode... that is taking care of it right now.

Comment: Also, it seems to be that most of the fields are duplicated through each entry of the tracking process, since you do not group by on them. You could consider normalising your data structure and place whichever columns you use min() or group_concat() on to a separate table. This way the where criteria will filter against a smaller table.

Comment: If you're really after a quick fix, to make MySQL work faster, the solution is simply to use an engine that's able to utilize RAM efficiently. You mentioned that at the beginning of your question. For a quick fix, I'd convert to `InnoDB`, raise `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to the amount that can hold the data set (6M rows). I/O will shift from HDD to RAM and then you'll at least have somewhat quick MySQL search. After that you need to deal with sending all that data back, decompress it, convert it from JSON etc.

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: 20 GB in total @RickJames

Comment: Dear Shadow and Mjh I've explained redesigning probability below for @Rick James. I'm sure i'm lacking efficient query things, as it is clear from above query. If you can help me same data by a better query that will in a way help it...

Comment: Please note getting result in <60 sec is good for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems...

It is not 'proper' to `GROUP BY` one column while having other non-aggregate columns mentioned.  I think you should focus on untangling this.  Probably you need more than one table holding the data.

Leading wildcard cannot use an index -- '%DACA'.

The only index that is usable is INDEX(`ship-date`), but that is not very useful, as you found out with (`ship-date`, `track-item-number`).

Comment: Thanks Rick, I'm not very good with database but yet I also felt dividing it into 2 or more table could be very effective, And which will be the first choice by default. Unfortunately it cannot be done, because of numerous reason one of them is that these tables (currently 150+) as well as their fields (some may have 150+) are created dynamically from a constant data feed from our mother concern. They as well as us don't know the actual number of table or fields in a table could be... we are not in a position to lost a single piece of data... I know it is not clear to all..but redesigning NP

Comment: Also a surprising factor (to me) the above query takes 1200 to 1600 seconds to run for the first time then every consecutive runs takes <50 Seconds... what is the reason behind that? is it the caching thing if so how can I maintain <50 Sec. state all the time?

Comment: is it ok to use  `right('ursa-code', 4) not in ('DACA', 'CGPA', 'ZYLA')` instead of `NOT LIKE'%DACA' AND NOT LIKE '%CGPA'` ....

Comment: Using `RIGHT(...) NOT IN ...` would be faster, but still every row would need checking.

Comment: "50 seconds" -- The first time you run _any_ query after restarting the mysqld server (or the whole server), nothing is cached in RAM, hence slow due to I/O.  Solution:  Don't turn off your machine.

Comment: Actually I didn't explain rightly, by _First time_ i meant if i run the query after few hours. But once it done running if i run the same query in every few minutes then it takes <50 seconds time. I need to run this query few times everyday.

Comment: The 'cache' can get 'cold' in two ways:  restarting (which I mentioned); or other activity bumping things out of cache.  The latter is probably what you are experiencing.  Please provide `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE "track-item-number"` for further discussion.

Comment: `show table status like 'track-item-number'` giving me empty result... am I doing it right?

Comment: Oops, I meant to use the table name:  `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE "shipment-profile";`

Comment: `id`...if I going to use MIN or MAX for all fields other then group_concat... will it be bit faster?

Comment: The speed won't change much.  The intent of the query will improve.

Comment: I've done profiling as advised by @Mjh and it seems taking all the time in sending_data option... which I guess normal in my case... but is there anyway I can make it faster...Or if i replace where clause with a query from other table using index columns like `where 'track-item-number' in (select 'track-item-number' from tbl_manifest where 'ship-date'>xxxxx` will it be faster('track-item-number' and ship-date is indexed on tbl_manifest)... do i need to include all fields (shipment-profile) in the index to make it faster?

Comment: `IN ( SELECT ... )` will probably perform _worse_.  Focus on restructuring your one table into multiple tables to avoid the need for `MAX()`, etc.  Either the problem will go away, or we can discus the new schema further.